# Error on inserting a form value to database

Tags: plugin-development, forms, wpdb

hi i have decided to store few values in a separate table, So i created it and now i used a form to store values but when i process that form i'm getting error `Trying to get property of non-object` and `Call to a member function insert() on a non-object` Even though i declared `global $wpdb;`

Here is the form

```
<form action="formaction.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name1" value="">
    <input type="text" name="name2" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="add">
</form>
```

formaction.php

```
if(isset($_POST['name1']))
{
    $db_data1=$_POST['name1'];
}
if(isset($_POST['name2']))
{
    $db_data2=$_POST['name2'];
}
function res()
{
 global $wpdb,$db_data1,$db_data2;
        $my_table_name=$wpdb->prefix."my_table";
        $name1=$db_data1;
        $name2=$db_data2;
        $rows_affected = $wpdb->insert( $my_table_name, array( 'first' => $name1, 'last' => $name2 ) );
}

res();
```

according to error $wpdb is not an object but i have used global, what is the bug in this code? am i doing correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're posting directly to `formaction.php`, as such WordPress is never loaded and so you do not have access to any of its API, including the database API stored in `global $wpdb` (which is causing the error). I'd recommend keeping everything in WordPress... and a useful method for form handling is using `admin-post.php` (if you're familiar with WordPress' ajax handling - this is a similar idea).

The idea is that you post to the url

```
 .../wp-admin/admin-post.php
```

which you can get via `admin_url('admin-post.php');`. And you post - along with any data and nonces - a **unique** value for the `action` variable. (Let's say `wpse111797_form_submitted`). When the form is submitted to `admin-post.php`, WordPress will trigger the hook:

- `admin_post_wpse111797_form_submitted` - if you are logged **in**
- `admin_post_nopriv_wpse111797_form_submitted` - if you are logged **out**

So your form might look like:

```
<form action="<?php echo admin_url('admin-post.php'); ?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="wpse111797_form_submitted">

    <input type="text" name="name1" value="">
    <input type="text" name="name2" value="">

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="add">

</form>
```

*Please don't forget to uses [nonces](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) to verify intent*.

You can then hook onto either of the above hooks (or both) depending on whether you want to handle form submissions from logged in users, guests, or both.

```
function wpse111797_form_handler(){

   global $wpdb;
   $name1 = isset( $_POST['name1'] ) ? $_POST['name1'] : null;
   $name2 = isset( $_POST['name2'] ) ? $_POST['name2'] : null;

   //TODO Check nonces & permissions first!

   $my_table_name=$wpdb->prefix."my_table";

   $rows_affected = $wpdb->insert( $my_table_name, array( 'first' => $name1, 'last' => $name2 ) );

   //Redirect user to a 'success' page, or from back whence they came!
}

//Attach callback to hook (in this case, the hook for logged-in users)
add_action( 'admin_post_wpse111797_form_submitted', 'wpse111797_form_handler' );
```

Comment: Thanks for your understandable answer to me. So what ever i do with php i should hook it otherwise it will come out of wordpress right?

Comment: Sorry i have used the form directly, that too causing me a problem.i wanted to add a Add New button in top of table and if user click on Add New this form should appear.What is the best idea to make this inside WordPress itself?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not able to go into specifics of your implementation. But the above is a general guide on how to implement form handling on custom admin pages. R.e. the problems you're experiencing, there could be syntax errors - but in principle the code is ok. I suggest turning `WP_DEBUG` on and finding out where its failing and go on from there.

Comment: why i can't able to see `admin_post_wpse111797_form_submitted` in codex document.is this familiar way to store datas?

Comment: There's nothing on the Codex about this, you'll have to go to [source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/admin-post.php) to see what's happening.